# How should image EXIF information be handled?

Tags: image, exif

I noticed that all my browsers:

- Mozilla Firefox
- Google Chrome
- Microsoft Edge
- Internet Explorer

seem to ignore image EXIF orientation data.

But other programs are orienting the images when they are opened/displayed:

- Google Mail
- MS Paint
- IrfanView
- Windows Explorer

We have a webpage on which users can upload images. I am asking, because users are complaining that the uploaded images look diferent/rotated than when opened on their local device using an image viewer. It seems to become an icreasing problem as more and more users are using smartphones and cameras to upload images directly without using any image editing software.

Here you can find some example images that have EXIF data in their header: https://github.com/recurser/exif-orientation-examples

**Question:** Since the browsers are ignoring the EXIF orienting should one auto-apply them on the uploaded images and then strip them from the header? Why are browsers ignoring EXIF information? What to do?